# Install an ipa file on iphone programatically in ios

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

Could someone please advise whether it is possible to install an `ipa` file programmatically in `iOS`that has been generated by `Adhoc` release ?

I have an application that when clicking on a button, it install another application, that is an `ipa` file (fetched from a server).

I have tried the following, but it does not work:

```
   string url = "https://192.168.27.45/apps/TruckApp.iOS.plist";
   NSString stringUrl =  new NSString("itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url="+url);
   NSUrl fileUrl = new NSUrl(stringUrl);

   UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(fileUrl);
```

Comment: What language is your code example written in? It's not [tag:Objective-C] or [tag:Swift].

Comment: Pleas show the contents of TruckApp.iOS.plist

Comment: @AndreasOetjen : Please see the plist here : https://pastebin.com/YPSikuwG

Comment: I am using `Xamarin.iOS` for this. The code is  c# based.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things to be checked:

- In which way doesn't it work? Is there anything going on, or do you simply see nothing on the device?
- Ensure that `UIApplication.SharedApplication.CanOpenUrl(fileUrl);` returns true
- Did you specify the correct values (e.g. bundle identifier etc.) in the manifest file (`TruckApp.iOS.plist`)?
- Check on the web server if the manifest / `.ipa` is being accessed (e.g. downloaded)
- Does the web server return the correct content type for the `.ipa` type - it is supposed to be `application/octet-stream`. If you are using Microsoft IIS, it sometimes "misbehaves"